# Como declarar IF no Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, if

Estou com o seguinte códio, ele verifica o valor de _meditaTotal se for maior que 70 a variável icone recebe 'verde', se for menor q 70 e maior que 50 variável icone recebe 'amarelo' e se for menor que 50 variável icone recebe 'vermelho', mas ele está aparecendo so vermelho na página.

```
public descritores;
public _mediaTotal: number;
public icone;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
this.descritores = navParams.get('anoSelecionado');
this._mediaTotal = this.descritores.icone;

    if (this._mediaTotal > 70){
      this.icone = 'verde';
    } 
    else if (this._mediaTotal < 70){
      this.icone = 'amarelo';
    }
    else (this._mediaTotal < 50)
      this.icone = 'vermelho';

}
```

Comment: `this.descritores.icone` é tipo numérico ?

Comment: Sim, this.descritores.icone são do tipo numérico, com duas casas decimais, exemplo: 81,16.

Comment: Verifique se this.descritores.icone está vindo mesmo como numérico usando console.log(typeof this.descritores.icone); . Para ter certeza que está comparando numerico por usar no if ( Number(this._mediaTotal) > 70) etc.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no algoritmo, para o que você precisa pode usar o seguinte:

```
if (this._mediaTotal > 70){
  this.icone = 'verde';
}
else if (this._mediaTotal > 50){
  this.icone = 'amarelo';
}
else{
  this.icone = 'vermelho';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if ((this._mediaTotal < 70) && (this._mediaTotal > 50)){
  this.icone = 'amarelo';
}
```

Conserte a condição do meio, no seu caso se media for 30 ele e menor que 70 e menor que 50, cerifique que ele só vai atender a 1 condição.